# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getResponse' of undefined

Tags: google-forms

I am trying to write a script, that automatically sends an email when the form is submitted. This is the code I wrote:

```
function autoEmail(e) {

    var response = e.response;
    var formResponses = response.getItemResponses();

    var email = formResponses[1].getResponse();
    var name = formResponses[2].getResponse();
    var size = formResponses[3].getResponse();

    var subject = "Confirmation";
    var body = "Dear " + name + " your size is " + size; 

    MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body)
}
```

When I try to run this simple code, I get: **TypeError: Cannot read property 'getResponse' of undefined**

Comment: We have no idea what `e` is...

Comment: `e` is the active form that has been submited.